# Flash Actionscript + detecting collision at edges

Tags: flash, actionscript, collision, geometry, bounds

I have two circular objects. I'm trying to detect as soon as the circles touch. The trace detects a collision when one circle reaches the center of the other but I want the collision to be detected as soon as the circles touch.

My two symbols are coin_mc and mugbounds_mc.

```
function checkHitArea(evt:Event)
{

 if (coin_mc.hitTestPoint(mugbounds_mc.x,mugbounds_mc.y, true)) {
  coin_mc.x=-1;
  coin_mc.y=-1;

                trace("Hit Mug"); // Is triggered when coin_mc reaches center of mugbounds_mc
        }
        else
        {
                trace("Didn't Hit Mug");
        }
}
```

Comment: You could use the Pythagorean formula for the distance between two points and if it's smaller than the sum of your two object's radii, they must be colliding. Check this out: http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/2009/05/08/pythagorean-distance-between-two-points/

Comment: hey when you paste your code in here select it all afterward and hit the little code button above the textarea to get it format correctly... in general think you're looking for is this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001314.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkHitArea)

function checkHitArea(e:Event) 
{
    a.x += 2;
    if (a.hitTestPoint(b.x,b.y, false)) 
    { 
        // do our in-circle check
        if((a.x - b.x) * 2 + (a.y - b.y) * 2 <= (a.width/2 + b.width/2) * 2)
        {
            trace("hit");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        trace("Didn't Hit Mug");
    }
}
```

I renamed your movie clips to a and b.

Comment: Thanks! :) The collision detection works great but how do I stop 'a' from moving? I need it to stay still and act as a barrier.

Comment: NM got it :) removed a.x += 2;. Now that the collision is detected how do I stop b from going into a? I thought it would be something like

a.x=-1;
a.y=-1;

to move 'a' back 1 pixel in either direction when a hit a hit occurs. Obviously I'm wrong so how do I do it?:)

Comment: I might do something like store the last known location of the clip internally and if a hit is detected, then reset the position to the last known location

Comment: Thanks for the tip shaunhusain. I've been Googling for a few hours now Demian to find out how to get a clip's x,y coords but haven't come up with anything. Could you give me a little information as to what I should search for?